# "Горючесмазочные материалы"

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно пишется слово "горючесмазочные материалы"? Слитно ли, через дефис или раздельно?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Грамота.ру и википедия предлагают нам дефисное написание слова.

Это кажется логичным, если обратиться к определению:"Горюче-смазочные материалы (сокращённо ГСМ) — нефтепродукты, к которым относят различные виды горючего и смазки, в основном в применении к автотранспорту: топливо (бензин, дизельное топливо, сжиженный нефтяной газ, сжатый природный газ), смазочные материалы (моторные, трансмиссионные и специальные масла, пластичные смазки), специальные жидкости (тормозные и охлаждающие)".

Здесь мы имеем сочинительную связь основ, для проверки можно использовать союз И:  горючие и смазочные материалы.

Answer (score 2):

Тут упоминали "Орфографический словарь-справочник" Букчиной за 1998 год. В 2011 году она изменила свое мнение и в словаре "Слитно? Раздельно? Через дефис?" написала *горюче-смазочный*.
Дело в том, что Букчина рассчитывала на реформу русского языка и писала *горючесмазочный* по новому правилу, которое так и не было принято. Правило звучало так: "Написание сложных прилагательных основывается не на смысловых компонентах сложных слов - подчинительных или сочинительных, а на формально-грамматическом принципе: наличии или отсутствии суффикса в первой части сложного прилагательного".

Так что правильно писать через дефис.

Comment: Интересно, в этих правилах речь идет именно о суффиксе прилагательного  или об основе прилагательного в первой части сложного слова. В нашем случае мы имеем основу прилагательного ГОРЮЧ-, вряд ли этот вариант должен попасть под "формально-грамматический принцип".

Comment: Я не до конца понимаю эту логику реформаторов. Для сравнения: южно-кавказский предлагали писать через дефис, а горючесмазочный - слитно. Может, вы сможете объяснить, в чем тут разница с точки зрения грамматики?

Comment: Видимо, имеется в виду суффикс прилагательного, которого здесь нет: от горючее.

Comment: У реформаторов логика одна: как бы из нашей смысловой (грамматической) орфографии сделать что-нибудь хоть и бессмысленное, но простое для решения и запоминания. (Хорошо еще, что у них это не всегда получается). Логику в написании сложных прилагательных можно найти, однако начинать надо с определения ЗНАЧЕНИЯ ФОРМЫ НАПИСАНИЯ. Но никто этого не делает, а я могу поделиться с обществом только своими наблюдениями, например такими.

Comment: ДЕФИСНАЯ форма письма - это промежуточная форма между слитным написанием слов и раздельным написанием словосочетаний. В каждой теме решение имеет свои особенности - в нашем случае я могу предположить, что очень часто дефисное написание сложного прилагательного - это УДОБНАЯ (УСЛОВНАЯ) ЗАПИСЬ ДВУХ ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫХ с однородной или неоднородной сочинительной связью, например книжно-журнальная продукция (книжная и журнальная), всемирно-историческое значение (всемирное историческое). Тогда Северо-Кавказский федеральный округ - это Северный Кавказский федеральный округ.

Comment: При СЛИТНОМ написании сложного прилагательного  мы должны определить способ и логику  его образования. Если написать горючесмазочный - это будет чистое сложение опорного прилагательного СМАЗОЧНЫЙ с основой ГОРЮЧЕ-, и тогда мы будем считать, что речь идет о смазочных материалах с особым свойством горючести, а это не так.

Comment: > Тут упоминали "Орфографический словарь-справочник" Букчиной за 1998 год. В 2011 году она изменила свое мнение и в словаре "Слитно? Раздельно? Через дефис?" написала горюче-смазочный. Дело в том, что Букчина рассчитывала на реформу русского языка и писала горючесмазочный по новому правилу, которое так и не было принято.

Вот и доверяй после этого этим словарям.

> Видимо, имеется в виду суффикс прилагательного, которого здесь нет: от горючее.

Видимо, на этом основании от реформы и отказались.

Answer (score 0):

[В Орфографическом словаре-справочнике](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/rus_orthography/18302/горючесмазочный) это слово написано слитно. Общее правило на тему правописания сложных прилагательных:http://yarus.aspu.ru/?id=101

Comment: Здесь вот еще что интересно. В толковом словаре указано: ГОРЮЧИЙ 1. Способный гореть. Г. материал. 2.  горючее,  ср. Топливо для двигателей: бензин, керосин и т. п. Из этого следует, что в сочетаниях "горюче-смазочные материалы, горючие и смазочные материалы" слово "горючее" является ПРЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫМ, а не существительным.

Comment: Ну, я лично только как о прилагательном (в этом сочетании) о нем и думала.

Comment: Скорее всего,  колебание формы написания связано не столько с новой и старой орфографией, сколько с совпадением форм существительного и прилагательного. Если считать, что горючее - это существительное (что правильно с точки зрения смысла), то слитное написание вполне возможно - сравнить: хлебобулочные изделия. С другой стороны сам термин ГСМ уже содержит слово "материалы", а это формально означает, что "горючие" - это прилагательное. Так что выбор оказался здесь не таким простым и однозначным.